# How do frameworks like codeigniter do their page caching?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, outputcache

I know that codeigniter seems to save the view output for a specified number of minutes, and if s user requests that page again within that many minutes, it will serve the saved version of the page instead of processing the request again. It seems to save all output from the view in a file, but how does it do that? And then, how does it know what the expire time for these cached files are?

On top of that, how would one create login security for pages using this type of cache model?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In lieu of a templating system, it would probably use `ob_start` and friends to capture and save output. The preferred way to make caching work is honoring conditional HTTP headers `If:` and `If-Modified-Since:`. Though I have no idea if CodeIgniter really does that or just relies on preconfigured timeouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At line 177 of CodeIgniter.php in core/:

```
if ($EXT->_call_hook('cache_override') === FALSE)
    {
        if ($OUT->_display_cache($CFG, $URI) == TRUE)
        {
            exit;
        }
    }
```

It checks for a cached file and displays this instead of processing the controller/action code.

You can also read how the cached file is checked for expiration by the Output class before it is being displayed.

```
function _display_cache(&$CFG, &$URI)
{
    $cache_path = ($CFG->item('cache_path') == '') ? APPPATH.'cache/' : $CFG->item('cache_path');

    // Build the file path.  The file name is an MD5 hash of the full URI
    $uri =  $CFG->item('base_url').
            $CFG->item('index_page').
            $URI->uri_string;

    $filepath = $cache_path.md5($uri);

    if ( ! @file_exists($filepath))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if ( ! $fp = @fopen($filepath, FOPEN_READ))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    flock($fp, LOCK_SH);

    $cache = '';
    if (filesize($filepath) > 0)
    {
        $cache = fread($fp, filesize($filepath));
    }

    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
    fclose($fp);

    // Strip out the embedded timestamp
    if ( ! preg_match("/(\d+TS--->)/", $cache, $match))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Has the file expired? If so we'll delete it.
    if (time() >= trim(str_replace('TS--->', '', $match['1'])))
    {
        if (is_really_writable($cache_path))
        {
            @unlink($filepath);
            log_message('debug', "Cache file has expired. File deleted");
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    // Display the cache
    $this->_display(str_replace($match['0'], '', $cache));
    log_message('debug', "Cache file is current. Sending it to browser.");
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: interesting, but what if the page is supposed to be behind a login. if it doesn't make it to the controller, how can a developer add session permission checks?

Comment: also, seems like such a shame to have to preg_match and preg_replace the entire file contents each time, there has to be a better way to time the expiration.